# How to stream a specific user_id by tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I'm trying to reach out an event to recognize whenever specific user tweets , so im using stream.filter in tweepy , just like

```
class IDPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):

def on_tweet(self, tweet):
    print(tweet)
printer = IDPrinter("bearer")
printer.sample(expansions=['author_id'],user_fields=['1234']) #consider 1234 user_id to follow
```

but `Stream encountered HTTP error: 400` ,what am i missing? im having api v2 and allowing OAuth v2 as well

Answer (score 0):

To be able to filter streaming data you need to give rules initially. So if you want to stream tweets of user with id `1234` you need give a rule for that, then when you start streaming, tweets that satisfy your rule will be retrieved.

For more information about adding rules on tweepy : [StreamRule](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamrule.html)

For more about Twitter Api v2 Filtered Stream : [How to build a rule](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule)